# what is hypercrunching in microsoft ajax minifier?

Tags: javascript, minify, microsoft-ajax-minifier

The Microsoft Ajax Minifier enables you to improve the performance of your Ajax applications by reducing the size of your Cascading Style Sheet and JavaScript files.

what is the difference between crunching and Hyper crunching in Microsoft ajaxMinifier  . i already tried in google but i didn't get correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you use normal crunching, the Microsoft Ajax Minifier strips all
>   comments, unnecessary whitespace, curly-braces, and semicolons from a
>   JavaScript file. Surprisingly, just removing all of this unnecessary
>   code fluff can make a significant difference to the size of a
>   JavaScript file.
>
> When you use hypercrunching, the Microsoft Ajax Minifer gets more
>   aggressive about reducing the size of a JavaScript file. In
>   hpercrunching mode, the Microsoft Ajax Minifier shortens the names of
>   local variables (variables in functions but not global variables) and
>   it removes unreachable code.

In essence, hypercrunching does normal crunching + shortening variable name + removing unreachable code.
[source](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/10/16/using-the-new-microsoft-ajax-minifier)